# Realtime css/less/scss edition using chrome DevTools in meteor

Tags: css, meteor, less, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm

I want to raise [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755209/realtime-css-scss-edition-with-meteor-avoiding-server-restart) question again.

What was suggested in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755209/realtime-css-scss-edition-with-meteor-avoiding-server-restart) question is to use old fashioned approach:

1. Store css in `public` folder, and incude it via `<link href=`
2. Add `public` folder to google chrome devtools `workspace`

Not a rocket science at all. Works, but two things I don't like with this approach:

1. It's still not native and for production I will have to move files from `public` folder
2. Each time you edit css, meteor notices changes and reloads application. Author of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22755210/2555999) answer ignored it.

**Basically this result I want:**

- I start meteor project, open chrome developer tools
- Each time I edit css in chrome developer tools it automatically changes in project.

[image]

**Problems:**

- Meteor performs concatenation of all css files [even with `--debug` flag on](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1876#issuecomment-57272441). But provides source maps.
- Meteor will still reload after file changes, but fortunately for styles meteor performs `soft injection`, I would call it, so page will not really be reloaded. It's okay and not really a problem.

Because of 1st problem [and this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277885) I can not get it work.

***This feature is very important for me in terms of productivity.***

**I would offer a good bounty for some guru, who could give me a direction to solve this. Maybe you point me to some starting points to make a plugin for chrome, this also would be acceptable**

Comment: I might have to read everything twice as it's not very clear, but as a first quick hint, did you consider using something like the Workspaces in Devtools [https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces)

Comment: @RaduChiriac Sorry, edits to make my question clear would be appreciated. Yes, It was suggested in the answer to the old question. Workspace is what we have to use for sure. But it does not work with meteors concatenated css.

Comment: Have you tried using browser-sync from npm?

Comment: Possibley a solution for problem #2 https://github.com/NucleusIDE/meteor-live-update

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is pretty simple.

1. Open your website
2. Right click -> inspect element
3. Click on Settings - (the wheel in the top right corner).

3.1. Select `General` tab and look for `Sources` label (around the bottom). There search for `Enable CSS source maps` and `Auto-reload generated CSS`. Check both. You can check all the features if you want.

4. Select `Workspace` tab and add the project folder.
5. Refresh devtools/browser and repeat everything to step 2.
6. Now, open the `Source panel` (Elements - Network - Source). Navigate through your folder and find the css file.
7. Right click on it and select `Map to file system resouce`. A window with few css files should appear (depends on your projects config).

7.1 Select the css file for your project. A popup asking you to restart devtools will appear. Click ok. Enjoy.

Comment: Are you sure you do this with `meteor`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's meteor or not. All you need to do is point the path to your css/scss/less files. The browser will do the rest

Comment: I linked my question to the similar one and the answer was exactly the same as yours, but more specified for meteor. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22755210/2555999 I'm not aware of what google documentation says, the only reason is that it does not work for meteor. See my question. I said that meteor concatenates all css in one, chrome dev tools can not handle it.

Comment: Of course this does not work as Meteor puts the (compiled or not) sources inside the .meteor folder during the build process, and the files that are loaded by the browser are just copies of the actual project source you work with. Changes would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this with Meteor, but for Harpjs & static HTML files the [Chrome LiveReload extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en) will inject changes in Chrome Dev to the actual file.