# HTML components developement. Light-weight, fast solution with browser auto-reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, ide

Let's say I want to make a new framework that consists of HTML components.
My project structure would be something like this:

```
/components
../dialog
../../css
../../js
../../html
../textfield
../../css
../../js
../../html
```

I need some technology to run such project that will give me:

- instant browser reloads/hot code pushes
- less/sass support
- template engine like handlebars, so for each component I don't need to import all my css and write `html` `head` tags

So basically I need something that works like [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/) but with the power of my `IDE` (I use webstorm)

What I tried:

- `ExpressJs` - I don't like the fact I should define routes for every component, also still can not configure it with any hot push packages: `nodemon`, `node-supervisor` - they reload app, but not page in the chrome.
- `Ember` - requires and generates a lot of `temp` code, that causes my 8gb ram computer run slow, since my IDE tries to index all of node_modules. I know it could be configurated, but no other advantages too.
- `Angular` - also a lot of steps I should do after creating new component files - imports and so on.
- `Meteor` - one of the best solutions so far, but it has full tech stack - `client` & `server`. Reloads a little bit slow. Aslo I know [exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030921/realtime-css-less-scss-edition-using-chrome-devtools-in-meteor) that it can not be used with Chrome Dev Tools Workspaces, to edit css instantly from console and save to disk, this feature I dream on.

To avoid any confusion. As a result I want to provide users with css/less/sass and html/jade/...
It should not be like web components: Polymer or React

Comment: Take a look at [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to automate the sass compiling. Depending on how you write your gulpfile, could refresh the page whenever you save. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thank you Taylor, I will try gulp!

Comment: @TaylorKirkpatrick I tried gulp and absolutely happy with it. BrowserSync is exactly what I wanted, and gulp gives me perfect control of how I want my files to be served to browser. Thank you! You can write it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for compiling your sass with BrowserSync. Gives a lot of customization in how you compile, when to compile, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `React` from Facebook.  It's a client framework that only generates the View.

- Combined with `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` you can get hot code pushes to your page.
- Combined with `less-loader` or `sass-loader` you can get LESS/SASS support.
- Combined with `babel-loader` you can run JSX for templates, which is an HTML-like markup.  Also allows you to use the new ES6 features by transpiling.

Comment: Thank you. Can I then export my components in plain html/css? Avoiding react?

Comment: No, sorry.  I had thought you were looking to implement a new framework, not build one.